# Regex gives incorrect output

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

I am trying to parse the output of running the prsqlcache command against a SYBASE server and store output information into a table. Each column information is stored as a scalar and saved into an array after which the whole array is BCP'd in into the target table.

As a sample, I have given two example outputs of the cached statements. In the first statement cache information, the SQL Text contains names of columns that I am trying to extract, hence when I use the code that I wrote, it breaks as there is more than one occurrence each of SSQL_DESC, ssql_name, etc.

The easiest solution would be to remove the line containing SQL Text which I grepped to find and removed, thinking I didn't need that information. But it turns out I need that too. Is there a way to make this work with my existing logic?

**input file sample**

```
Start of SSQL Hash Table at 0x0x2aacbdfdf050
Memory configured: 1024000 2k pages Memory used: 109219 2k pages
Bucket# 000 address 0x0x2aacbdfdf050
SSQL_DESC 0x0x2aad268cb8b0
ssql_name *ss1530075878_1111638016ss*
ssql_hashkey 0x0x42424000   ssql_id 1530075878
ssql_suid 31838     ssql_uid 1063880    ssql_dbid 14    ssql_spid 0
ssql_status 0x0x81  ssql_parallel_deg 1
ssql_isolate 1      ssql_tranmode 32
ssql_keep 0     ssql_usecnt 1   ssql_pgcount 20
ssql_optgoal allrows_oltp   ssql_optlevel ase_default
opt options bitmap  00809f172c6181fffb160500008009000000000000000000000000000000
SQL TEXT: select SSQL_DESC = 'addadads',ssql_name='aasass', ssql_hashkey='ssdddssddcs', ssql_id =1345, ssql_suid =4344, ssql_uid =2344, ssql_dbid=11, ssql_spid=0,ssql_status=0x024, ssql_parallel_deg=1, ssql_isolate = 1, ssql_tranmode = 32, ssql_keep = 1, ssql_usecnt =9, ssql_pgcount =8, ssql_optgoal = 'allrows', ssql_optlevel ='wee', opt = 'options', bitmap = '1235ddf3445553334' from table1
SSQL_DESC 0x0x2aad268cb8b0
ssql_name *ss1530075878_1111638016ss*
ssql_hashkey 0x0x433424030  ssql_id 1443475244
ssql_suid 553   ssql_uid 1443   ssql_dbid 15    ssql_spid 1
ssql_status 0x0x22  ssql_parallel_deg 1
ssql_isolate 1      ssql_tranmode 62
ssql_keep 0     ssql_usecnt 1   ssql_pgcount 22
ssql_optgoal allrows_oltp   ssql_optlevel ase_default
opt options bitmap  00809f172c6181fffb160500008009000000000000000000000000000000
SQL TEXT: select column from table
```

**code snippet**

```
foreach my $line (@file){
    #print $line;
    my $string = "SSQL_DESC";
    my $string1 = "ssql_name";
    my $string2 ="ssql_hashkey";
    my $string3 = "ssql_suid";
    my $string4 = "ssql_status";
    my $string5 = "ssql_isolate";
    my $string6 = "ssql_keep";
    my $string7 = "ssql_optgoal";
    my $string8 = "bitmap";

    if ($line =~ /$string/i) { 
        my @sentence = split ' ', $line;
        $sql_desc = $sentence[1];
    }

    if ($line =~ /$string1/i) { 
        my @sentence = split ' ', $line;
        $sql_name = $sentence[1];
    }

    if ($line =~ /$string2/i) { 
        my @sentence = split ' ', $line;
        $sql_hashkey = $sentence[1];
        $ssql_id = $sentence[3];

        print Dumper \@sentence;
    }

    if($line =~ /$string3/i){
        my @sentence = split ' ', $line;
        $ssql_suid = $sentence[1];
        $ssql_uid = $sentence[3];
        $ssql_dbid = $sentence[5];
        $ssql_spid = $sentence[7];
    }

    if($line =~ /$string4/i){
        my @sentence = split ' ', $line;
        $ssql_status = $sentence[1];
        $ssql_parallel_deg = $sentence[3];
    }

    if($line =~ /$string5/i){
        my @sentence = split ' ', $line;
        $ssql_isolate = $sentence[1];
        $ssql_tranmode = $sentence[3];
    }

    if($line =~ /$string6/i){
        my @sentence = split ' ', $line;
        $ssql_keep = $sentence[1];
        $ssql_usecnt = $sentence[3];
        $ssql_pgcount = $sentence[5];
    }

    if($line =~ /$string7/i){
        my @sentence = split ' ', $line;
        $ssql_optgoal = $sentence[1];
        $ssql_optlevel = $sentence[3];
    }

    if ($line =~ /$string8/i) {
        my @sentence = split ' ', $line;
        $ssql_opt = $sentence[1];
        $bitmap = $sentence[3];

        @array = ($sql_desc, $sql_name, $sql_hashkey, $ssql_id, $ssql_suid, $ssql_uid, $ssql_dbid, $ssql_spid, $ssql_status, $ssql_parallel_deg, $ssql_isolate, $ssql_tranmode, $ssql_keep, $ssql_usecnt, $ssql_pgcount, $ssql_optgoal, $ssql_optlevel, $ssql_opt, $bitmap);
        #print Dumper \@array;
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'ssql_hashkey',
          '0x0x42424000',
          'ssql_id',
          '1530075878'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          'SQL',
          'TEXT:',
          'select',
          'SSQL_DESC',
          '=',
          '\'addadads\',ssql_name=\'aasass\',',
          'ssql_hashkey=\'ssdddssddcs\',',
          'ssql_id',
          '=1345,',
          'ssql_suid',
          '=4344,',
          'ssql_uid',
          '=2344,',
          'ssql_dbid=11,',
          'ssql_spid=0,ssql_status=0x024,',
          'ssql_parallel_deg=1,',
          'ssql_isolate',
          '=',
          '1,',
          'ssql_tranmode',
          '=',
          '32,',
          'ssql_keep',
          '=',
          '1,',
          'ssql_usecnt',
          '=9,',
          'ssql_pgcount',
          '=8,',
          'ssql_optgoal',
          '=',
          '\'allrows\',',
          'ssql_optlevel',
          '=\'wee\',',
          'opt',
          '=',
          '\'options\',',
          'bitmap',
          '=',
          '\'1235ddf3445553334\'',
          'from',
          'table1'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          'ssql_hashkey',
          '0x0x433424030',
          'ssql_id',
          '1443475244'
        ];
```

Comment: Make an array of array references or hash of array references and whenever you get to `$string8` or maybe `SQL TEXT`, add the current array you're building to the array/hash of array references and start building a new one.

Comment: Yes, @Borodin did provide a solution for exactly what you mentioned. I played around with the solution and I am starting to understand hashes more now. This I feel is a good start for me, as I am new to Perl and not much of a programmer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you find yourself writing many scalar declarations all to to be used in a similar way then you should think of using a *hash* straight away. The same applies to a sequence of variables whose names are all the same except for an index number on the end: those should be an *array*.

The nicest way to deal with this is to treat the `SQL TEXT` line as a special case. It is also useful because it is always the last line of each block, and so can serve as a trigger to dump the data found so far.

I have used an array `@fields` to contain the names of all the fields to be extracted. It is simple to derived a regex that matches any of the field names by `join`ing them with a pipe `|` alternation operator.

Thereafter it is only necessary to find all occurrences of any field name in each line of the file, and extract the following data field. All of this is stored in hash `%data`.

I have hard-coded `ssql_opt` as `"bitmap"` because it always seems to be the same. If this is wrong then you must explain how to get its value out of the file. I suspect that, in fact, there may be may `opt` values, and you will have to reconsider how these are to be represented.

I haven't rebuilt your final `@array` because it's not clear that it is anything but a debugging artifact. If you need it then it is just `my @array = @data{@fields}`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Data::Dump;

my @fields = qw/
  SSQL_DESC
  ssql_name
  ssql_hashkey      ssql_id
  ssql_suid         ssql_uid          ssql_dbid         ssql_spid
  ssql_status       ssql_parallel_deg
  ssql_isolate      ssql_tranmode
  ssql_keep         ssql_usecnt       ssql_pgcount 
  ssql_optgoal      ssql_optlevel 
  bitmap
/;

my $re = join '|', @fields;
my %data;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {

  if ( $line =~ /^(SQL TEXT):\s*(.*)/ ) {

    $data{$1} = $2;

    $data{ssql_opt} = "bitmap";
    printf "%-20s => %s\n", $_, $data{$_} // '<undef>' for @fields;
    print "$1: $2\n";
    print "\n";

    %data = ();
  }
  else {
    $data{$1} = $2 while $line =~ /\b($re)\s+(\S+)/og;
  }
}

__DATA__
Start of SSQL Hash Table at 0x0x2aacbdfdf050
Memory configured: 1024000 2k pages Memory used: 109219 2k pages
Bucket# 000 address 0x0x2aacbdfdf050

SSQL_DESC 0x0x2aad268cb8b0
ssql_name *ss1530075878_1111638016ss*
ssql_hashkey 0x0x42424000   ssql_id 1530075878
ssql_suid 31838     ssql_uid 1063880    ssql_dbid 14    ssql_spid 0
ssql_status 0x0x81  ssql_parallel_deg 1
ssql_isolate 1      ssql_tranmode 32
ssql_keep 0     ssql_usecnt 1   ssql_pgcount 20
ssql_optgoal allrows_oltp   ssql_optlevel ase_default
opt options bitmap  00809f172c6181fffb160500008009000000000000000000000000000000
SQL TEXT: select SSQL_DESC = 'addadads',ssql_name='aasass', ssql_hashkey='ssdddssddcs', ssql_id =1345, ssql_suid =4344, ssql_uid =2344, ssql_dbid=11, ssql_spid=0,ssql_status=0x024, ssql_parallel_deg=1, ssql_isolate = 1, ssql_tranmode = 32, ssql_keep = 1, ssql_usecnt =9, ssql_pgcount =8, ssql_optgoal = 'allrows', ssql_optlevel ='wee', opt = 'options', bitmap = '1235ddf3445553334' from table1

SSQL_DESC 0x0x2aad268cb8b0
ssql_name *ss1530075878_1111638016ss*
ssql_hashkey 0x0x433424030  ssql_id 1443475244
ssql_suid 553   ssql_uid 1443   ssql_dbid 15    ssql_spid 1
ssql_status 0x0x22  ssql_parallel_deg 1
ssql_isolate 1      ssql_tranmode 62
ssql_keep 0     ssql_usecnt 1   ssql_pgcount 22
ssql_optgoal allrows_oltp   ssql_optlevel ase_default
opt options bitmap  00809f172c6181fffb160500008009000000000000000000000000000000
SQL TEXT: select column from table
```

**output**

```
SSQL_DESC            => 0x0x2aad268cb8b0
ssql_name            => *ss1530075878_1111638016ss*
ssql_hashkey         => 0x0x42424000
ssql_id              => 1530075878
ssql_suid            => 31838
ssql_uid             => 1063880
ssql_dbid            => 14
ssql_spid            => 0
ssql_status          => 0x0x81
ssql_parallel_deg    => 1
ssql_isolate         => 1
ssql_tranmode        => 32
ssql_keep            => 0
ssql_usecnt          => 1
ssql_pgcount         => 20
ssql_optgoal         => allrows_oltp
ssql_optlevel        => ase_default
ssql_opt             => bitmap
bitmap               => 00809f172c6181fffb160500008009000000000000000000000000000000
SQL TEXT: select SSQL_DESC = 'addadads',ssql_name='aasass', ssql_hashkey='ssdddssddcs', ssql_id =1345, ssql_suid =4344, ssql_uid =2344, ssql_dbid=11, ssql_spid=0,ssql_status=0x024, ssql_parallel_deg=1, ssql_isolate = 1, ssql_tranmode = 32, ssql_keep = 1, ssql_usecnt =9, ssql_pgcount =8, ssql_optgoal = 'allrows', ssql_optlevel ='wee', opt = 'options', bitmap = '1235ddf3445553334' from table1

SSQL_DESC            => 0x0x2aad268cb8b0
ssql_name            => *ss1530075878_1111638016ss*
ssql_hashkey         => 0x0x433424030
ssql_id              => 1443475244
ssql_suid            => 553
ssql_uid             => 1443
ssql_dbid            => 15
ssql_spid            => 1
ssql_status          => 0x0x22
ssql_parallel_deg    => 1
ssql_isolate         => 1
ssql_tranmode        => 62
ssql_keep            => 0
ssql_usecnt          => 1
ssql_pgcount         => 22
ssql_optgoal         => allrows_oltp
ssql_optlevel        => ase_default
ssql_opt             => bitmap
bitmap               => 00809f172c6181fffb160500008009000000000000000000000000000000
SQL TEXT: select column from table
```

Comment: ssql_opt is not a field. Bitmap in itself is a field. And in any case I would definitely not want to hard code any values, in case SYBASE makes changes to the structure of the output of cache statements. This solution is what I was looking for rather than a half baked version of mine for the same reason, in case SYBASE alters structure of the output contents.
@array was needed, which is used to BCP in into the target table. Retrieving all the information, including the SQL TEXT information wasn't difficult.

Comment: @Borodin Impressive bit of deciphering.